# Sull'uso attuale di "dopodiché"

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

So che "dopodiché" ha lo stesso significato che "dopo di che", ma quello che ha attirato la mia attenzione è l'uso di entrambe le forme nello stesso testo letterario. Nel romanzo *La testa perduta di Damasceno Monteiro* di Antonio Tabucchi ho letto questa frase:

> «Dunque, specificò l'avvocato, per lo meno fino alle due il Monteiro è rimasto nel commissariato, *dopo di che* il Torres ha pensato che era opportuno rientrare a casa e se n'è andato.»

Nello stesso libro, però, c'è anche quest'altra lunghissima frase:

> «E a quel punto si discussero le emicranie di Titânio Silva, di questa parte Firmino colse qualche spezzone, l'esibizione di un certificato medico che attestava che il sergente Silva era affetto da terribili emicranie derivanti dalle lesioni a un timpano per lo scoppio di una mina che gli era esplosa accanto in Angola, ma che lui non aveva mai preteso una pensione dallo Stato, e che a causa dei suoi disturbi era dovuto rientrare a casa sua per prendere un'iniezione di Sumigrene, lasciando il cadavere del Monteiro sul pavimento, *dopodiché* i due agenti cominciarono a balbettare che sì, effettivamente ora capivano, ora si rendevano conto che l'imputazione poteva essere occultamento di cadavere, ma quella sera non avevano pensato al codice penale, fra l'altro loro il codice penale lo conoscevano male, erano talmente angosciati, talmente impressionati, e così avevano portato via il corpo e l'avevano lasciato nel parco comunale.»

Ho scritto la frase completa perché, secondo me, si tratta di un ricorso dell'autore per esprimere la sensazione di fatti che accadono molto in fretta che ha Firmino, il giovane giornalista che sta presenziando il processo contro un sergente e due agenti della "Guarda Nacional". Non so se l'uso di "dopodiché" abbia qualcosa a che vedere con questo ricorso stilistico.

Cercando il vocabolo *dopodiché* nel [Vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dopodiche/) ho trovato

> **dopodiché** locuz. avv. – Grafia unita, rara, per *dopo di che*

ma questo mi sembra molto curioso perché io credo di aver letto la forma *dopodiché* parecchie volte in testi recenti. Potreste dirmi qualcosa sull'uso attuale di *dopodiché*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Io non lo trovo né particolarmente raro né desueto. È una forma blandamente colloquiale, direi, per cui non è frequentissimo trovarlo scritto (ed in effetti in entrambi i casi che citi tu è parte di un discorso diretto).

Non mi sembra che nello stralcio lungo che citi da Tabucchi l'uso della forma  unita concorra particolarmente a dare il tono affrettato del pezzo. Io personalmente non vedo motivazioni importanti per aver scelto in un caso una grafia e in un altro l'altra. Le trovo veramente equivalenti da ogni punto di vista.

Answer (score 1):

È ben possibile che si tratti di una scelta dell'autore per contribuire a velocizzare, almeno nella lettura, un tratto specifico di un periodo molto ingarbugliato in cui i fatti si susseguono in rapida successione ma anche in modo confuso, con le accelerazioni e decelerazioni improvvise di un flusso di coscienza. Ma come dice giomasce potrebbe anche non aver importanza: i due termini sono altrimenti del tutto intercambiabili.

Il Treccani ha ragione a riportare *"dopodiché"* come forma [più rara](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dopodich%C3%A9%2Cdopo+di+che&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdopodich%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdopodich%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDopodich%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cdopo%20di%20che%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdopo%20di%20che%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDopo%20di%20che%3B%2Cc0) di *"dopo di che"*, sebbene guardando il grafico sia ragionevole prevedere che la situazione in futuro si ribalti (o che lo sia già ora).

Sui siti de *La Repubblica* e de *Il Corriere della Sera* ([1a](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=aVQyVPm2G-PC8geosYDgDA&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22dopo+di+che%22+site:www.repubblica.it), [1b](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=aVQyVPm2G-PC8geosYDgDA&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22dopodich%C3%A9%22+site:www.repubblica.it), [2a](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=aVQyVPm2G-PC8geosYDgDA&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22dopo+di+che%22+site:www.corriere.it), [2b](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=aVQyVPm2G-PC8geosYDgDA&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22dopodich%C3%A9%22+site:www.corriere.it)) prevale nettamente la grafia disgiunta.

---

Se mi posso permettere una piccola digressione, secondo me *"dopodiché"* è un *avverbio* e non una *locuzione avverbiale* come riporta il Treccani; *"dopo di che"* è invece una *locuzione avverbiale*.

Per me la regola è semplice: le [locuzioni](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/locuzione_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) sono composte da **più** parole; una parola è una stringa di lettere senza spazi intermedi: *"wxyz"* è una parola, *"wx yz"* è una locuzione. La stringa di lettere *"dopodiché"* è senza spazi interni, quindi è una singola parola, non una locuzione, benché sia pacifico che sia *originata* da una locuzione. Nessuno direbbe che *"[tuttavia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tuttavia/)"* sia una locuzione avverbiale in quanto originariamente prevalente in grafia disgiunta, *"tutta via"*, no?